# SMB share name changes case

Tags: network-share, server-message-block

There is some unexpected behaviour of Windows SMB shares.

If a share is named all-uppercase, then it changes case depending on how you enter server name.

Hence if there is an example share named "SHARE", then entering `\\SERVER` in Windows Explorer results in share name appearing as "share", and entering `\\server` or `\\Server` results in "SHARE".

At the same time, shares with both upper- and lowercase characters in name are presented as they are named, so "Share" will remain "Share" in both `\\SERVER` and `\\server (\\Server)` cases.

It looks like the problem is in SMB protocol, as all windows versions seem to have this problem. In my case there is Windows Server 2016, and shares get listed from Windows Server 2016 and Windows 7 computers.

What could be the solution for this problem? (i.g., how to make SMB display names properly regardless of server name?)

Comment: What is the problem? You just describe a behaviour.

Comment: @Sven The problem is this behavior changes how names are displayed, which sometimes make users confused.